# Comparing function to parent function without graphing

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, transformation, absolute-value

How can I compare this function to the parent function without graphing? Where did the 5/4 come from and what steps do I need to take to solve this?

[image]

Comment: Any suggestions as to solving this?